# Asus Xonar DX issues: Windows cannot play sound

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, sound-card

The following is my hardware:

- Asus Xonar DX 7.1 PCIE sound card
- Razor Tiamat 7.1 headset
- Logitech 5.1 speaker set (physically disconnected)

The cables for the Tiamat in- and output are correctly plugged into the 5 ports available on the Xonar DX.

Using the Xonar DX Audio Center, I can confirm that the output cables are connected correctly. When using the 8Channels, PCM 44.1 KHz, 7.1 Speakers Analog Out setting, with SPDIF Out set to PCM/7.1 Virtual Speaker, it plays the test sounds at the correct speakers on my headset.

When opening the Windows Volume Mixer, opening Playback devices, I can select the following:

- Speakers (ASUS Xonar DX Audio Device, default)
- S/PDIF Pass-through Device (ASUS Xonar DX Audio Device)
- Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)
- Realtek Digital Output(Optical) (Realtek High Definition Audio)

Flash (in FireFox) is currently attempting to output to the last one: The optical output, however no sound is coming out of the headset. When running the 7.1 audio test from the audio center, it does not show up in the Windows Volume Mixer as sound is being played, even though I can clearly hear it.

Applications like VLC and TeamSpeak are having a hard time loading the audio devices list, and when they do, I cannot get them to output any sound to the headphones, no matter what setting I'm trying. Also, when attempting to play the Windows test sound through the volume mixer to the Speakers, I'm getting the message: "Failed to play test tone.".

Does anyone know this issue, or have any suggestions on troubleshooting? I'd really like to use the Tiamat with my sound card and start playing games again.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this question or why.. Please let me know why so I can take your advise into concideration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Xonar drivers aren't Windows 8+ compatible. Installing UNi Xonar solved the issue.